# createElement broke inline-block display

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Why createElement function is not holding inline-block whitespace between elements?

[Example problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mGRj.png)

First rectangle with normal html string concatenate:

```
var htmlString = '<div class='inline-block'...></div>'
$(parent).html(htmlString);
```

Second rectangle output with createElement DOM elements:

> var htmlString = createElement('div');
>
> htmlString.className('inline-block');
>
> ...apendChild(htmlString);

Why diferent output?

Thanks

Comment: is there a space in the markup between the first and second block when you print this with js? Can you recreate this in a http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: `var htmlString = '<div class='inline-block'...></div>'` has unescaped `'` in string

Comment: Just a example idea not a copy paste code. Why the DOM object created not looks same like .html(string)

Comment: Show us a proper example that reproduces the problem, and we'll tell you. [mcve]

Comment: Well create a reproducible example using **runnable code**. There is also an option to include runnable code in your post.

Comment: @sabithpocker did the OP send you their code? How do you know that the code you added to the post is what the OP did? You could very easily be creating a red herring that doesn't actually solve the problem. Fixing a minor syntax error might be okay but I'd advise against making assumptions to what the OPs code might be. Even when it seems obvious.

Comment: Well, I just added existing code to a context. The main intention is just to give OP the idea on how to insert runnable code.

Comment: @sabithpocker I understand you're trying to help but you've gone beyond the scope of what was provided and filled in a lot of unknowns. If what you've filled in doesn't accurately represent the OP's code then the community might give unhelpful answers based on something that isn't the core issue.

Comment: @hungerstar Your concern sounds legitimate, will keep it in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a space between elements, create and append a `textNode` between them.

When you add a `String` to HTML the string get parsed as HTML during that process one or more whitespaces are combined to form a single whitespace which generates a `textNode` which is done by HTML parser. When you do with `createElement` string to HTML parser is not involved so the textNodes need to be generated by yourselves. Consider it as yourself generating HTML with more control and responsibility.

```js
var parent = document.getElementById('parent');
var htmlString = document.createElement('div');
htmlString.className= 'inline-block';
var textNode = document.createTextNode(' ');
var htmlString2 = document.createElement('div');
htmlString2.className= 'inline-block';
parent.appendChild(htmlString);
parent.appendChild(textNode);
parent.appendChild(htmlString2);
```

```css
.inline-block {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent"></div>
```

`\n` should also do the same thing, don't know how you tried to add line break.

```js
var parent = document.getElementById('parent');
var htmlString = document.createElement('div');
htmlString.className= 'inline-block';
var textNode = document.createTextNode('\n');
var htmlString2 = document.createElement('div');
htmlString2.className= 'inline-block';
parent.appendChild(htmlString);
parent.appendChild(textNode);
parent.appendChild(htmlString2);
```

```css
.inline-block {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent"></div>
```

Comment: Nice, fast answer. Why happens? Thanks

Comment: @recoco inline elements will have whitespace around them if there's whitespace in the markup. Your HTML string probably had a single space between DIV elements. When you created the DIVs via `createElement()` and appended them to the DOM that single space didn't exist. See this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/538gLLh0/) for an example. `.two` and `.three` in the JSFiddle likely represent what you had in your HTML string and `.one` is similar to how you created them with JS.

Comment: @hungerstar Oh really, i set '\n' my code. Thanks. I was wrong.

Comment: How did you set `\n` it should also do the same, can you show how you added line break?